# Courant condition for diffusion

Tags: diffusion

What would be the courant condition for the following diffusion equation,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=A(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right).$$
For $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$$
I know the courant condition which is $$\frac{\delta t D(x)}{\delta x^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$ but I am not sure whether the courant condition for the first equation is
$$\frac{\delta t A(x)D(x)}{\delta x^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$ or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is correct but it might be important to use the maximum value of the functions $A(x)$ and $D(x)$ in the domain of interest